# Java ArrayList contains method does not identify integer data type

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am creating an ArrayList with mixed data types of string and integers. Then I am using contains method to identify and print specific members. Though the contains method identifies string, it does not appear to identify integer values present in the list. How can I check for integer values in a mixed type list?

Code:

```
public class ArrayListClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList mixArrayList = new ArrayList();

        ArrayListClass ArrayListObj = new ArrayListClass();
        mixArrayList.add("Alpha");
        mixArrayList.add("Beta");
        mixArrayList.add("Gamma");
        mixArrayList.add("Delta");
        mixArrayList.add(1);
        mixArrayList.add(2L);
        mixArrayList.add(3.0);
        mixArrayList.add(4F);
        mixArrayList.add(ArrayListObj);

        System.out.println("mixArrayList is "+ mixArrayList);

        if (mixArrayList.contains(2)) {
            System.out.println("List contains 2");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("List does not contain 2");
        }
        if ((mixArrayList.contains("Gamma"))) {
            System.out.println("List contains Gamma");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("List does not contain Gamma");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
===========
mixArrayList is [Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta, 1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, ArrayListPractice.ArrayListClass@b4c966a]
List does not contain 2
List contains Gamma

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What you added to the list was a `Long` of value `2`, not an `Integer`.

Comment: It's obvious as you are adding 2L (Long) and checking for 2 (Integer). You should not use raw form of ArrayList or any collection APIs to avoid runtime issues.

Comment: Your `mixedArrayList` should still be declared as `List<Object> mixedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: What is `ArrayListClass`?

Comment: Learn to use Java naming conventions for readable code. An object reference variable should be named with first letter in lowercase, not `ArrayListObj`.

Comment: In all honesty, _having_ a list of mixed types is a code smell.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - So what do you suggest to use if I have mixed data types for a field to be handled as a collection, and have to code decision logic in the code based on individual values?

Comment: In Scala you could use `Any` or `AnyRef`. So maybe in Java you could use `Object`. But then again, I don't think I've ever had a practical need for `Any` or `AnyRef` in Scala...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are generic classes. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) by Oracle.

So when you do the following:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2L);
```

The `2L` [boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) as a [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html), whereas `2` boxes as an `Integer`.

So `list.contains(2)` looks for an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) and thus won't find your `2L` entry.

Comment: Thank you. I was somehow thinking the types were interchangeable in use for small numbers. But I was wrong.

Comment: Can you also please explain why I should use List<Object>  mixArrayList= new ArrayList<>(); instead of what I have used ArrayList mixArrayList = new ArrayList();. It seems to be working that way. I might be missing something but just wanted to know the difference of specifying one way rather than the other. I am new to Java.

Comment: Sometimes, your code will work in Java even if you don't conform to recommended practices.  Threads is a good example of that.  Check out this answer on why using raw types should not be used.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 0):

It is because `2` is not the same as `2L`.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things in my local Scala REPL:

```
scala> val num = new java.lang.Integer(2)
num: Integer = 2

scala> val sameNum = new java.lang.Long(2)
sameNum: Long = 2

scala> num.equals(sameNum)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> sameNum.equals(num)
res1: Boolean = false
```

This is relevant because `ArrayList<E>.contains(Object key)` calls `indexOf(Object key)` and returns true if that gives anything more than −1, and `indexOf()` in turn calls `equals()` defined by the class of `key` (or a superclass of that class). At least this is the case in Java 8; I doubt it has changed.

And `Integer.equals(Object other)` checks that `other` is an instance of `Integer` and `Long.equals(Object other)` checks that `other` is an instance of `Long`. They're both direct subclasses of `Number`, so an instance of one won't be recognized as an instance of the other by `equals()`.

I suppose if you really wanted to you could make your own version of the JDK in which each of the subclasses of `Number` define `equals()` to unbox the held value if `other` is any instance of `Number` and compare them as primitives. Since, after all,

```
scala> 2 == 2L
res7: Boolean = true

scala> /* and... */ 2L == 2
res8: Boolean = true
```

I'd probably soon drop the idea of rewriting the JDK, after asking myself: "What do I need this for anyway?"